# Image not found after dyno falls sleep django heroku postgresql

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, django-admin

I have a small Django app with admin site deployed on Heroku. Each time that the dyno falls sleep all the media files (images) that I have preloaded before in the admin site disappears. I am not sure if the images are stored properly in the postgresql database or if they are not stored in the database, just in the media location. All the rest is working, just the image that is not found after the dyno falls sleep. What can I do? Here is my code:

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Service(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    description = models.TextField()
    enable = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    image = models.ImageField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from . import models

class ServiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("title","enable")

    def image_img(self):
        if self.image:
            return u'<img src="%s" />' % self.image.url
        else:
            return '(No image found)'
    image_img.short_description = 'Thumb'
    image_img.allow_tags = True

admin.site.register(models.Service, ServiceAdmin)
```

settings.py

```
import os
import dj_database_url

PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

POSTGRES_URL = "HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_<NAME>_URL"
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default=os.environ[POSTGRES_URL])}

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

If you need something else, please let me now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating the images in the admin site you are saving them to a Heroku dyno in the media directory. The behavior you are experiencing is expected because Heroku uses an [ephemeral filesytem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). Dynos are cycled every 24 hours (and possibly when they sleep) so any files that you have created or modified directly on Heroku are discarded. You need to store uploaded images somewhere with persistence like Amazon S3. You can also add the images to your repository, commit, and push them to heroku as long as your slug size stays below 300 MB

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you now if there is other solution rather than Amazon S3? The thing is that it take charge for the usage, but I only need that app for a month, for that reason I used Heroku. Anyway thank you

Comment: You could always just add them to your repository locally and commit and push the images to Heroku that way. It's not ideal but as long as your slug size is <300MB it should work.